# How to set output directory and map drive letter

Tags: php, batch-file, scripting

I am writing a very basic batch script to run an MD5 hash. I need it to ask the user for an output directory, then ask for an IP address output, then map a drive letter to this output. I can get it to ask, but it doesn't output the file to the chosen directory. It puts it in the local directory the script was run from. It also won't map a drive letter to it.

```
@ECHO OFF
pause

REM This section prompts user for output location 

:start
CLS
set /p direct="Enter the directory output location: "

dir %1 %direct% > investigation.txt 
pause

REM This section prompts user for IP output location

set /p direct="Enter the IP output location: "

dir %1 > investigation.txt 
pause

REM Map share 

@echo Map Share

@echo off 
net use z: 
\\%1
pause
```

edit

The MD5 hash is what will be written to the txt file. 
Can anyone explain how to get it to output to the user entered directory and how to map a drive letter to that location?

Comment: You seem to be confused what `%1` is used for. It is a parameter passed to the batch file when you call it.

Comment: Why do you have a php tag?

Comment: …what information is supposed to be output to investigation.txt

Comment: You might want to consider using different variable names for your `set /p` input commands.

Comment: Crossposted to [su]. Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
@echo off
set /p dir="enter directory: "
set /p ip="enter ip: "
net use Z: \\%ip%\%dir%
echo "asdf testing testing 1 2 3 ..." > Z:\output.txt
```

This code uses descriptive yet appropriately short variable names, and appropriate syntax for the `net use` command.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The output file is still going to the local directory and not the directory I entered. 

Net use is not mapping the Ip to a drive, it gives an error 67.

Comment: is the host you are attempting to connect to live, and are you entering it's ip right? does it have an active share? 67 usually means either the host doesn't exist, or it can't find it.